# List all caches in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Is there a way to list all caches in Oracle with SQL query? I would like to list all available information about them in Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition.

Comment: it seems you dont want to help you . okay then read this https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA640 and this https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/query-result-cache-11gr1 then youll understand why I asekd you that

Comment: Ok, how many caches are in Oracle?

Comment: as the document explains , there are ways to get the caches , I have never use this way to be honest but I am trying to help you . would this query helpful 
select * from V$RESULT_CACHE_OBJECTS

Comment: @PeterPenzov are you interested in *what* is cached, or just looking for *how much* data is cached?  There are several different types of caching in Oracle, the answer would probably be a list of different queries for each one.  Off the top of my head, there's the buffer cache, in-memory (potentially including the whole database), result cache, subquery caching, etc.  This might require a community Wiki answer.

Comment: Can you show me for all caches that you know SQL queries to get the required data?

Comment: Have you checked on SYS.CACHE_GROUP?

Comment: No, can you give complete answer, please?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has many different types of caches.  There's no single query to display them all.

1. **Buffer Cache (SGA)**  This is the most important cache, it contains blocks of tables, indexes, and other objects.  Generally, the most active and most recently used
   objects will be in the buffer cache.  But the algorithms surrounding the size and persistence of objects in the buffer cache are complicated and partially undocumented.
2. **Shared Pool (SGA)**  This is a collection of multiple caches that contain SQL queries, stored procedures, data dictionary, etc.
3. **Session and Client Caches (PGA)**  Normally the Program Global Area is used to store query specific data, such as sorting and hashing areas.  But it also contains
   program variables, which means it can sometimes be used as a cache.
4. **In-Memory Option**  An option to cache column-oriented data, and potentially the entire data.
5. **SQL Result Cache**  Caches the results of a specific SQL query.  This cache is not often used and must be manually enabled.
6. **PL/SQL Function Result Cache**  Caches the results of a function.  This cache is also unusual and must be manually enabled.
7. **Subquery Caching**  Some subqueries are automatically cached, improving query performance.  For example, `select (select count(*) from large_table) from another_large_table;`
   may run much faster than you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please add SQL queries for every cache how to list and count the content?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM   v$parameter
  WHERE name LIKE 'result_cache%';

Not sure if i understood your question correctly. But this query will give you result_cache_mode, result_cache_max_size, result_cache_max_result, result_cache_remote_expiration. Hope it helps.

Thanks.